# C++ regex capture group confusion

Tags: c++

I'm implementing the nand2tetris Assembler in C++ (I'm pretty new to C++), and I'm having a lot of trouble parsing a C-instruction using regex. Mainly I really don't understand the return value of `regex_search` and how to use it.

Setting aside the various permutations of a C instruction, the current example I'm having trouble with is `D=D-M`. The result should have `dest = "D"; comp = "D-M"`.

With the current code below, the regex appears to find the results correctly (confirmed by regex101.com), but, not really correctly, or something, or I don't know how to get to it. See the debugger screenshot. `matches[n].second` (which appears to contain the correct `comp` value) is not a string but an iterator.

Note that the 3rd capture group is correctly empty for this example.

```cpp
auto regex_str = regex("([AMD]{1,3}=)?([01\-AMD!|+&><]{1,3})?(;[A-Z]{3})?");
regex_search(assemblyCode, matches, regex_str);
string dest = matches[1]; // this automatically casts some object (submatch) into a string?
string comp = matches[2]; 
string jump = matches[3];
```

[image]

I will note, though, that `D=D+M` works, but not `D=D-M`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc warns about unknows escape sequence `\-` [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7e4bc397f4a3470).

You have to escape `\`,

```cpp
std::regex("([AMD]{1,3}=)?([01\\-AMD!|+&><]{1,3})?(;[A-Z]{3})?");
```

or use raw string

```cpp
std::regex(R"(([AMD]{1,3}=)?([01\-AMD!|+&><]{1,3})?(;[A-Z]{3})?)");
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a7b308b81a8a139)